# Extending String native type in Typescript

Tags: oop, typescript

I would like to extend the String type in Typescript.
Here's my code :

```
export class Str extends String{
    constructor(str: string) {
        super(str);
    }
}
```

The problem is, after the call of the String constructor using `super(str)`, the value of my new type stills empty.

I have the same problem with another type extending the native Array type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is transpiled to:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var Str = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Str, _super);
    function Str(str) {
        _super.call(this, str);
    }
    return Str;
})(String);
```

And the problem is that you no longer deal with the original native type that has special properties (like `+` operator on two strings). So your extended type - even if you would have succeded - would be severely limited and confusing for others.

Details and gotchas can be found Axel Rauschmayer's article: http://www.2ality.com/2013/03/subclassing-builtins-es6.html

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for your answer. Does that mean that Typescript is not able to extend native type? If so the only way is to write Javascript code?

Comment: Well, it's not built TypeScript to handle these special cases, so `extends` keywords does not work out of box. The problem is that I don't think you can fully create your own string with properties of the built-in type. So you are left with the option to modify built-in type and that is a terrible idea.

Comment: OK thanks. Actually I already have a workaround. I was just trying to refactor my code to make it cleaner. That's too bad I was not able to do this with Typescript.